# How to show validation error messages on the right side of the input field in a tooltip using angular js?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have form which contains some fields and have validated these fields by using angular.validator. The error messages are displayed under every fields. But I want to display this error messages using tooltip. For example , if some particular field is not valid , the error message should be shown on the right of the field box. I didn't found a solution from other posts of stackoverflow. How to do this ?[image]

I want to show this field is required in a tooltip. ( by making directive) .

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact No</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" ng-model="proFormSubmit.contactNo" validator="[required, number]" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="" validation-message="Only numeric values are valid!">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Profile Picture</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8 companyLogo"> <img src="assets/img/user.png" alt="..." class="img-rounded col-sm-3 "> 
                <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" ng-model="proFormSubmit.profilePic">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Language</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="proFormSubmit.language" validator="[required]">
                  <option></option>
                  <option value="english">English</option>
                  <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address 1</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" ng-model="proFormSubmit.address1" validator="[required]" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address 2</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" ng-model="proFormSubmit.address2" validator="[required]" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">City</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" ng-model="proFormSubmit.city" validator="[required]" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">State</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="proFormSubmit.state" validator="[required]">
                  <option></option>
                  <option value="Indonesia">Tamilnadu</option>
                  <option value="Indonesia">Kerala</option>
                  <option value="Indonesia">Rajasthan</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: .., have u done it .,show an error message using tooltip .?? @arjun

Answer (score 0):

I use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap which has a $tooltipProvider that allows you to modify behavior of the tooltip. Other than that this seems like a CSS + ng-show candidate

Comment: the tooltip shows only when i click that particular field using the mouse. Its not working when i use tab to move to next field while leaving the current field unentered.